# "Not empty" set in one word?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms, programming

Is there a single word which means "not empty"? That is, a word which one might use to describe a field with one or more cows in it, as opposed to an "empty" field with none?

*Full* or even *partially-full* are not appropriate, because the number of animals is indeterminate, and the final count could be a single bull [which are best kept on their own] or fifty cows. Or three sheep. And the field is really only *full* when there is no more space available.

I'd prefer a single word, to go with the single word "Empty". Currently I'm using "has animals" which I feel is not particularly succinct.

*[This is an edit of the original question reproduced below, in an effort to keep it on-topic]*

---

I'm trying to figure out the names for different states of a set of items, empty or non-empty.
What I came up with so far:

```
EmptyAndFetching,
EmptyAndReady,
HasItemsAndFetching,
HasItemsAndReady,
Error
```

`HasItems` seems awkward, I would rather use one word than two.
How do you call a set that is not empty, i.e. has at least one item, in a common language?

Comment: You could use *Populated* but I prefer *HasItems*.

Comment: Off Topic: "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes".

Comment: @AndrewLeach That reads like “haslterns” in this font, as though Hazel had terns amongst her gulls. Yet another reason to write it as *has_items*, which is much easier on the eye.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry. `Populated` is an option, but I prefer `HasItems` (following the camelCase convention, which is admittedly not universally popular).

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the edit. The question is now clearly On Topic: The first item listed under "Ask about..." in [the tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) is "Word choice and usage".

Comment: Hi, I'm just going through posts which have "How do you call....?" in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing yours to *“What do you call a set ....?”* Thanks!

Comment: what about word `valid`?

Comment: @suhailvs Not really, I think: it's perfectly valid for a field to be empty.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Mathematicians always use the word *nonempty*.  Maybe you will like it, too.

> (of a set or class) not empty; having at least one element or member

Comment: +1 Especially since this seems to be for a computer program dealing with a set, and *nonempty* is often used of sets in computer science and programming too, so it is the *mot juste*.

Comment: @jonhanna +1 for mot juste! I concur.

Comment: 'non-trivial' is a common mathematical synonym.

Comment: Actually, "The milk bottle was nonempty" is different than "The milk bottle was nontrivial".

Comment: @Mitch while that is also used in computer science and programming, it is not synonymous with non-empty in those fields, nor in mathematics.

Comment: @JonHanna, GEdgar: I didn't say it was synonymous in natural English, nor that it was an exact synonym.

Comment: @Mitch, I also disagree that it is a common mathematical synonym.  In fact I would say it is used almost exclusively when there is a 'trivial' object (often a final object) that is different from (or when there is no) 'empty' object (often an initial object).  For example, a 'non-trivial' group is one that's not the identity, not just one that's not empty; and (perhaps more relevant) I'd expect a 'non-trivial' space, with no further context, to be one with more than one point.

Comment: @LSpice, JonHanna, GEdgar: Yes, you are all right. 'non-trivial' is similar but just not the same thing as nonempty.

Comment: @Mitch, ha, one of the rare instances where the sense of "all right" is not "it's all right"!

Answer (score 16):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/empty) has the following for *empty*:

> 1. containing nothing; having none of the usual or appropriate contents: an empty bottle.
> 2. vacant; unoccupied: an empty house.
> 3. without cargo or load: *an empty wagon.*
> 4. destitute of people or human activity: *We walked along the empty streets of the city at night.*

While there is no real antonym for (1) other than *not empty* or *containing liquid* (or cows), the other meanings do have single opposing words,

> **occupied; laden; populous/populated**

If those words aren't suitable, perhaps you might use them to find synonyms.

Comment: I'm abruptly a big fan of 'laden' to describe a string that is neither null, nor empty. I can cope with calling a string 'nonempty' or 'nonnull', but 'nonnull and nonempty' is too much of a mouthful, and really needs shortening given how frequently it's used in computing.

Comment: Agreed.  I hate using negatives for boolean names, 'populated' is too long, and 'hasItems' isn't an adjective. 'isLadenArray' sounds perfect.

Comment: In computer technical writings, it's common to use the term 'populate' when referring to the setting of a variable value.

Comment: @android.weasel plus it helps Python code with the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Naming) of Monty Python [references](https://youtu.be/tFylQ6_1bgQ?t=166).

Comment: Having said what I said, non-empty implies non-null, even if you have a nullable reference to a set. The question only really started coming up for me when I was forced to use Ruby: before it supported nil short-circuit with `bin&.empty? == false`, the code was even uglier and less comprehensible. Even now, I would still prefer the terser `bin.laden?`

Answer (score 6):

By mathematical terminology, you may consider *inhabited* or *nonempty*; both apply to sets. These usually carry the same meaning, but they may differ in non-classical mathematics. The difference is [explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhabited_set) on Wikipedia.

I believe you wouldn't mind calling cows inhabitants, would you?

Answer (score 2):

In French we use the term "habitation" to express a type which is not empty, i.e., a type for which there is some element of that type.   I suggest the same thing in English.  Either a set is empty or inhabited.

Answer (score 0):

I believed this has to be discussed for every example,
but for the cow field, occupied could work.