# A single word for "non-empty" or "not empty"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Much like the poster who posted this:

["Not empty" set in one word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word)

I'm simply looking for a single ("short" if possible) word that means "non-empty" or "not empty".  I'm not looking for the word "full".

For example, a cup can be empty, or it can contain some liquid, in which case you could describe it using the word I'm searching for.

None of the answers or comments in the above post really fit what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is an **exact** duplicate of the linked question. The accepted answer *non-empty* (with or without the hyphen) seems to fit. If it doesn't, **why** doesn't it?

Comment: filled ?..__..?

Comment: @AndrewLeach -- Because "non-empty" is not recognized as a word by Thesaurus.com, and thus I assumed it wasn't a word.  I see now that it's recognized by Dictionary.com.  Regardless, I was hoping for something less clumsy than "non-empty".

Comment: @roryap - it is an exact duplicate. What is confusing about that? If you do not give us reasons why the words there don't suit your needs, then this question gets closed as a dupe.

Comment: Can you give a sample sentence of how this short word (that is not going to be used as a datafield name) would be used Rory? Maybe there's a misunderstanding here.