# What do you call a set of data that contains the position and dimensions of something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an Element. I'm trying to find a name for a set of data that describes its position and dimensions. What can I call this set of data?

> Positions and dimensions can be referred to together as ______.

Comment: Please note that naming of variables is [**explicitly** off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because the name *susan* would work and function just as well. Please edit the question to make [a real-world example](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word).

Comment: That said, I doubt that you will find a better word than *properties*.

Comment: "The data"?  "A data set"?  "The values"?  "The criteria"?  What is it you're trying to do??

Comment: *Logistic* comes to mind but that's about more than just size and location.

Answer (score 2):

> Positions and dimensions together form a *plot* of the element.

**plot**, verb –[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plot)

> to determine and mark (points), as on plotting paper, by means of measurements or coordinates.
>
> to be marked or located by means of measurements or coordinates, as on plotting paper.

---

> noun: a plan, map, diagram, or other graphic representation, as of land, a building, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think of this as a **Vector** which is a one dimensional set of values.  Your Element = {X position, Y position, Length, Width, Height}  and whatever other information you might have that describes your Element. This is very common in mathematics and computer programming.

Comment: I agree with your choice of the term "vector", but I'm a mathematician and to a mathematician "one dimensional" is wrong here (as is the notation). However, I'm guessing you're speaking from a computer science perspective, in which case there's nothing wrong with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no term for this.
Reason : The dimension never changes with change in position of an object,So they are certainly two mutually exclusive properties of an object.
I would consider "**state space**" that is closely related to it.This defines the mass, acceleration, position & many more properties of an object.

Comment: The dimensions of an object change if it's going fast enough.  At least from my point of view.

Comment: @deadrat I don't think so..never came across such a theory..do you have any supported facts? For. ex. A spaceship wil not shrink when it runs on a speed of several light year per second.

Comment: Then you've never come across the theory of relativity.  This is called *length contraction*.  The observed length is reduced by a factor of sqrt(1-v^2/c^2).  And you think it's possible to cover a light year in one second?

Comment: Yes..Have heard of it & certainly it is ignored for regular purposes,so I gave a real time example..Oh thats a typo..per year :P