# Looking for a word that can represent position or size or both

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a program to create layouts.
I used the words `PLACE` and `SIZE` (I use caps cause they are constants, represented like that in the code).

`PLACE` was responsible for the x and y position.
`SIZE` was responsible for the width and height.

Later on I removed `SIZE`, and now only `PLACE` is used.
Therefor `PLACE` could be more seen as `PLACING`.

Yet I am not happy with that.

For example if you have a slider. Then there is the bar and the thumb.
The bar has to be placed, but for the thumb I only need to know the width and height cause the position of the thumb is decided by the scroll position.

I could use `POSITION` and `SIZE`, but I was wondering if there is any other word.

So basically i'm looking for a word that can both represent `POSITION`, and `SIZE` or either one of them.
Is there such a word, or something that comes close?

Comment: Have you considered layout

Comment: @Lliane thank's, that doesn't sound bad. I also have a layout system planned so I have to see if it clashes with that but I definitely keep it open.

Comment: How can position and size be only one word?

Comment: Ultimately, position and size resolve to coordinates.  You can use a coordinate system to define a shape, and also to position it, either absolutely or relatively.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'STATUS'.
According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
STATUS 
: position or rank in relation to others.

Comment: Position can be meant in different dimensions. The one you mentioned is a 1-dimensional position ("higher or lower"), what the OP meant is 2-dimensional - a completely different meaning. Think of it like this, you cannot use "rank" or "status" to compare between two points on a graph (or a box and a ball in a room, when we talk about 3 dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question, so I looked it up. The following two SE questions provide some answers:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/281459 - `Plot`
- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229772 - `State Space`

But also, that last question provided a better answer as a tag/title in my opinion: `geometry`

> the shape and relative arrangement of the parts of something.
> e.g. "the geometry of spiders' webs"

I think that `layout` is also a good answer, comparable to geometry.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ^ are you serious??? I've provided multiple variations of a good answer, with quotations, whereas the other person - that obviously didn't even read the question - somehow gets a pass. Good job 'community bot'.

Answer (score 0):

**Geometry** is the word used by [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#arg_geometry) to describe size and/or position.