# Looking for a word or phrase to describe "out of sthg"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How do you say when a source contains water, but it no longer has its water supplies? So if I pump out the remaining water it will be dry, but it is not dry now.

The same can happen for example by a mine, we can see that this one will be the last lode, and after that we have to close the mine, since we will be out of minerals.

Another example is money, we lost our job and we have some spare money which we know will run out soon. So we are out of money source, but not yet out of money.

Is there any special word, phrase to describe these conditions?

(I currently use dry and exhausted by the source, so I am looking for a better word than exhausted by that example, if that is possible.)

Comment: That water source is not replenished, it means that when the current reserve is out it'll be empty. Look up synonyms for that word if it doesn't suit you exactly.

Comment: You can use *running out* for all those examples (as you have). What's wrong with that?

Comment: @AndrewLeach `source.willRunOut()` does not look pretty. That's my problem.

Comment: in this case you could use also the very fashionable " non-renewable source" ie. source.unrenewed   or source.unrenewable

Comment: @AndrewLeach The `will run out` does not work here. I need something that stays `true` even after the source gets dry, but `source.willRunOut()` should give `false` by a dry source, since it has already run out... So it should be something similar to `turned off the taps`.

Comment: If you need your answer to work as a function name, please be aware that requests to help name something are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @P.O. Getting closer, probably `source.isRenewing` is better than `source.willRunOut`.

Comment: @MetaEd Ohh, sorry, I did not know.

Comment: I think it's possible to answer the question *and* provide a function name :-)

Comment: What I can't figure out is "Out of order".  Since order is such a common thing to run out of, why don't businesses just lay in an extra supply?

Comment: @HotLicks :D :D

Comment: source.isLimited, source.isRenewable(), source.isConsumed() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not used to my knowledge, but if a source is renewed in some way, it might be considered *sustained* or sustainable. My thinking would be that if it's not, then it might be called

> unsustained

It's not something I've heard someone say exactly, but there is the much used *sustainable* and *unsustainable*. So I do think someone would know what you mean with regard to resources if you were to mention that this is a sustained or unsustained resource. I don't think it works too well with money, but with natural resources, maybe.

For completeness sustained is also common in law, but used differently.

Comment: Thanks John! I `isSustained` is better than the `isRunning` I currently use. So after I block a source it can become `blocked` or `unsustained`. Unfortunately I cannot accept 2 answers and Andrew has a more general solution.

Answer (score 3):

One phrase which is used of resources which are not renewable (such as oil) is that they are **finite.**

> A non-renewable resource (also called a **finite resource**) is a resource that does not renew itself at a sufficient rate for sustainable economic extraction in meaningful human time-frames. An example is carbon-based, organically-derived fuel.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-renewable_resource) (my emphasis)

Addressing comments: A finite resource is still a finite resource after it's completely run out. It just has a zero quantity, *very* finite! Thus `source.finite()` will be `false` if it's being refilled at a sufficient rate, or `true` if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, it is a general solution. I ended up with `source.isRunning()` by the source example, but this is good as well. :-)

Comment: I don't understand why asking for function names is forbidden here, I always learned a lot from the answers to these questions. :-)

Comment: Naming questions are off-topic because you could name your function *Susan* and it would work just as well. Here, you specified your question in non-naming terms, which is fine (and only mentioned names in a comment). [Here's an extreme example](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771) which wasn't rescued in time to prevent closure.

Comment: @inf3rno The purpose of the site is to create a library of generally useful questions with answers. Acceptable answers to naming questions are generally not useful to anybody but the person who asked.

Comment: @MetaEd I don't think that's true. People who answer these questions may learn a lot about English just by thinking on the problem. :-)

Comment: @inf3rno Since comments are for constructive suggestions on the post they are attached to, let's take any further discussion of this to [chat].

Answer (score 1):

The words "almost" and "nearly" might help in those situations.  For example, "The pool is nearly empty," and, "The oil reserves are almost gone."

Answer (score 1):

A synonym of "exhausted" specific to a non-renewable resource is **tapped out**.

> out of money or another resources *[sic]*, such as energy
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tapped-out
>
> broke, spent, exhausted
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tapped%20out

The derivation is from "tap" meaning to draw a resource out of a supply, by analogy to the tap on a keg of liquid (or the "tap" leading into a water supply). When you've gotten everything you can get out of it, it's "tapped out," "exhausted," or (another possibility) **"spent."**

> - used up:  consumed:  exhausted of active or required components or qualities often for a particular purpose
> - drained of energy or effectiveness
>     http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spent