# What do you call people who receive donations?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

Is it right to say "Donated to?" or "Donored to" in reference to the needy who received donations?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You've tagged this "adjectives" but "What do you call people" might elicit a noun like ***recipients.*** *Donor* is definitely not a verb, so *donored* is out. I suspect this might be a [database-column question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word) rather than an English question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider [***donee*** (*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language* via *The Free Dictionary*):](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/donee)

> The recipient of a gift

The word appears frequently in legal texts. Examples (my emphasis):

> If the donor opens a bank account in the **donee’s** name and makes a deposit therein, the gift is not complete. The donor must inform the **donee** of what he has done so that the **donee** can sign the bank’s signature card.
>   [[Don Alan Evans, *Texas Business Law*, 1995.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=h917Cck_GO8C&pg=PA278&dq=donee&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6rfiT-PzOAhXHuBQKHcvqAwYQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=donee&f=false)
>
> Gifts have often been authorized for the purpose of reducing the taxable estate of an incompetent person and of increasing the amount available for his or her ultimate beneficiaries, with no purpose of aiding a needy **donee**.
>   [[*Restatement of the Law*, The American Law Institute, 2003.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2xk3AQAAIAAJ&q=%22needy%20donee%22&dq=%22needy%20donee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiauN_bgf3OAhUHPRQKHe_PBIgQ6AEIKjAD)

Answer (score 1):

People who receive donations are usually referred to as "Donor Recipients." You could structure the sentence any way you want, however, in order to convey what you want. You could say "John Doe, the recipient of the donation, wore a monocle during the event." Also, there is always the option of splitting the ideas into two easier-to-compose sentences. "Donated to" would be the better choice, but in order to truly answer, I think we need to know more about the sentence it will be in.