# A single word for not-full

Tags: single-word-requests

I find myself struggling to find a single non-hyphenated word that expresses the state between empty and full, assuming the container started off empty.

I want to emphasize on the state of being 'not-full'. So I am not allowed to use 'nonempty'.

The word can't be 'depleted' because it assumes a container that was once full, and now has 'lessened' and became nonempty or empty. The word I am looking for should assume a container that started off empty, and now is half-full.

Example context:

- We add the grains to a _____ silo.
- I put the box in a _____ warehouse.
- He parked the car in a _____ car park.

The closest word I can think of is 'unfull' but it isn't really a word. Is there a single non-hyphenated word that can express such state?

Comment: Is it 'filling' or 'emptying', or at a static level?

Comment: The context I am using it in is 'filling', but static works fine too.

Comment: I'd use ***unfilled*** rather than ***unfull***.

Comment: The need to suggest a starting point produces some difficulty. Without that requirement, I'd describe each location as **available**.

Comment: _He parked the car in a _____ car park_ - you'd park your car into an **empty** space.

Comment: 'Unfull' appears in Wiktionary and is quite common on the internet. I'd wager on it being in OED. This is the usual accepted test of wordness.

Comment: Unfilled is the closest candidate yes. Sadly there is ambiguity if used without context since it can mean it is empty (literally not filled).

Comment: In any remotely "formal" context I'd use a phrase - ***with spare capacity***, for example.

Comment: So what is wrong with *half-full*?

Comment: @Boondoggle: If it's a big enough container, you might still be happily choosing it to put things in, even when it's 90% or 99% full.

Comment: All of your examples can be completed with the word 'available'. But that would not express drinking from a half-full bottle of milk.

Comment: 'Partially filled' does not have a hyphen.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OED does have an entry for **unfull* but it is not very helpful. It only provides two quotes, both very old, and trying to read the definition gives an application error.

Comment: If I close-vote, it might magically close this question, but I consider that reasonable evidence of research should be shown. It seems inappropriate on ELU to have a fairly heavily upvoted answer as simplistic as 'unfilled'. This could perhaps have been found by looking in a thesaurus for 'full: antonym'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a thesaurus lookup question.

Comment: Like @NigelJ, I would use ***available*** here.

Comment: Related: [A word for not-empty](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word/102789#102789)

Answer (score 6):

I think *"unfilled"* would work:

- My bottle is unfilled.
- No unfilled spaces have been found.

> **unfilled**
>
> not filled
>
> - an unfilled bottle
> - unfilled spaces
> - a vacancy left unfilled
> - an unfilled order

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfilled)

Comment: This is probably as good as can be managed.

Comment: But an unfilled bottle *could* be empty. I don't know of any single English word that means "not empty, and also not full".

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - In fact, in my book, I would not expect *any* water in a bottle that was described as ”unfilled”.

Answer (score 2):

In the examples given by the OP, there is, in fact, no extra word required:

> We add the grains to a silo.
>
> I put the box in a warehouse.
>
> He parked the car in a car park.

The fact of 'adding' 'putting' and 'parking' includes the information that there was space there in which to 'add' 'put' or 'park'.

That is why we have no word for the concept. That is why the English language has developed without a word to express what the OP is trying to express.

Language develops from concepts.

Comment: The examples are merely attempts to show where the candidate _might_ be used. 'We hoped that there would be a _____ car park near the theatre.' The extra word **is** required to alter the meaning/

Answer (score 0):

I would conciser one of the following for your particular case:

- **Capacious**
- **Ample**

In review, capacious seems particularly applicable in this specific context as based on the definition from *www.dictionary.com*:

> **Capacious**: Capable of holding much; spacious or roomy. 
>  For example: "A capacious storage bin."

But I think the key here is to realize that the magnitude qualifier is dependent on the specific context.

You would probably not use a word like "empty" or "full" to describe the air contents of a balloon. In such case you would probably more likely use "deflated" or "inflated". The fact that "empty" or "full" are generally quite broadly applicable does not necessarily imply that there exists a word in between that is also broadly applicable. Though perhaps it should, if indeed it does not yet exist. Definitely an interesting situation.

Cheers,

Arty

---

*Edit*: Swapped in two new word suggestions that might fit more appropriately for the given context than the ones originally suggested ("growing" and "developing").

Comment: Can you think of a word that would match the static swnse the asker is looking for too?

Comment: I gave this one another go and for the particular context, I think either "capacious" or "ample" might be applicable words for the desired meaning.

Comment: *Capacious* doesn't describe how much stuff is currently in a container.

Comment: ... and 'ample' doesn't say what proportion of the container is full. A huge container 1/4 full, or a medium container 98% full?

Comment: @nnnnnn good point..!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You know what, you are right. Definitely not the ideal answer the question was looking for. Thanks for sharing your thoughts & wishing you best!