# I am looking for a word for an arbitrary collection of rooms

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for an arbitrary collection of rooms.

They might be all rooms on floor 2, all the bedrooms, or all rooms in a building.

The best I have currently is "Room Collection", but that of course, is not a word.

Comment: What is the context (namely the sentence where you would use the word)? And why doesn’t the obvious choice (simply the word “rooms”) not work?

Comment: The collective noun for a _connected_ set of rooms is of course 'suite'. I would think that an arbitrary set of rooms crops up so rarely that a collective noun has not been considered useful.

Comment: The form of this question bears an uncanny resemblance to [one I constructed some time ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth please add as answer so I can accept

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Go for it. There is no better alternative.

Comment: I'd mark the answer wrong. It doesn't work with 'all the bedrooms in a building', only with specially connected sets. The answer is almost certainly 'we haven't got such a word'. 'Set of rooms' is more felicitous.