# What is the best way to write a plural of a plural?

Tags: grammar, nouns, attributive-nouns

What started out as programming has turned into a curious language/grammar question.

I'm writing a program and want to clearly specify a variable name. The variable will be a dictionary and each item in the dictionary stores the details of a "revision".

```
variable = {
    "revision_a": {"detail_a": "", "detail_b": ""},
    "revision_b": {"detail_a": "", "detail_b": ""}
}
```

I want to name the variable `revision_details` but I don't believe it clearly communicates what the list is. If I saw a variable named `revision_details` I would assume that it stores details about a single revision.

```
revision_details = {"detail_a": "", "detail_b": ""}
```

In this case would `revisions_details` be correct grammar? If this is or something similar correct what is the official term for this and what does the correct version look like? Otherwise would I just need to find a different name like details_of_revisions or just revisions?

To clarify, what is the right way to say "revisions details", i.e. multiple details about multiple revisions?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. English has no such thing as plural adjectives.

Comment: I see no adjectives.

Comment: revisions_with_details

Comment: Maybe have `revision_details` for a single item and `collection_of_revision_details` for the whole set.

Comment: Surely what you have as `variable` is simply an array of revisions, so it would make sense to call that array `revisions`?

Comment: However, naming variables is [**explicitly off-topic**](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so you may want to rework your question into one about a problem with English, like [this earlier one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/not-empty-set-in-one-word).

Comment: The subtly of an *s* in the middle of a long name may lead to confusion. Not clear why *Revisions* wouldn’t suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would technically be something like

> revisions' details

But I don't know if you really wanted to put an apostrophe in your code. You should probably go with whatever will make the code clearest. Maybe just "revisions," though "revisions_details" is fine too.

The language you're discussing is kind of a cross between English and Python (or whatever coding language it is), so you can pretty much mix it as you like.