Adjective meaning "with gaps" or "with holes"
Is there a word that describes a list of items containing stretches of empty slots?
FOr instance, suppose I wrote this list on a piece of paper:
[1, 5, 23, 97, empty, empty, empty, 56, 234, empty, empty, 5464, 434, 4543, empty, 434, ...]

Is there a word to describe such a list?
[This is an edit of the original question reproduced below, in an effort to keep it on-topic]
I'm trying to name a data structure that consists of a list of values with a number of empty stretches between them. That is, the structure represents something like this:
[1, 5, 23, 97, empty, empty, empty, 56, 234, empty, empty, 5464, 434, 4543, empty, 434, ...]

I'm looking for an adjective that means "it has gaps", so I can name it AdjectiveList.
Something like GapToothedList, but using a single-word adjective so it is more concise. I might go with GapList, but I'd prefer a real adjective rather than an aposition.

non-continuous (or discontinuous) ?

FYI: Naming programming variables or classes is off-topic according to the Help Center. The programming context is not relevant to the main question about finding an adjective meaning "with gaps" or "with holes". The question is not about programming terminology, so The OP could just provide an everyday example sentence or context to keep it on-topic. (or could delete the part about naming perhaps).

How many of the values are "empty"? The majority? Only some? Or does it vary?

@carllacan Here's an example of a non-computing version of a computing question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102771/18696

I’m voting to close this question because programming is explicitly off-topic.

You would probably get a better answer on a mathematics or computer science forum. But one candidate is sparse, defined in Wiktionary as:

(mathematics) Having few nonzero elements

It is particularly used of matrices: a sparse matrix is according to Wikipedia

a matrix in which most of the elements are zero. There is no strict definition regarding the proportion of zero-value elements for a matrix to qualify as sparse but a common criterion is that the number of non-zero elements is roughly equal to the number of rows or columns. By contrast, if most of the elements are non-zero, the matrix is considered dense.

There are also sites that use terms like sparse array, for instance the Python library SciPy Sparse Arrays module scipy.sparse.

Exactly the right choice.

In my experience, calling something out as "sparse" usually means that something different, either in storage or processing, will be done to take advantage of this sparsity. If the OP is doing neither, I'd be a bit puzzled by the name.

This is exactly it, I totally forgot about sparse matrices

In a situation where humor is acceptable holey might work. It means "having holes" and is a homophone of holy.

it's a perfectly valid word; the homophone doesn't even make a pun (unless you're listing ["cross", "altar", None...])

If an adjective is required, “gap” can simply be replaced by “gapped”. If this is relatively rare usage in standard English, “GappedList” seems perfectly acceptable as the name of a programming data structure.

Yes, I was drafting a more detailed answer that also included the obvious adjective gapped, but decided not to post it. This is not a question about programming terminology indeed, and naming programming variables or classes is off-topic according to the Help Center. The OP could just provide an everyday example sentence or context.  PS: The OED lists adjectives such as gappy, holed and holey also.

As an IT professional, this sounds off to me. The only "gap" commonly used in IT contexts is the "air gap", a physical separation between networks, which is quite different to this.

@lambshaanxy and that leads to "air-gapped" as an adjective, which makes "gapped" feel wrong.  "GappyList" might be OK, I reckon because "gappy" isn't used in that way (IME)

@lambshaanxy — We all have different associations of words. When I did my IT masters degree “air gapped” hadn’t been coined. But the point is really that the poster liked “gap” and wanted an adjective. I supplied one.

@ChrisH — “Gappy” might be ok? For me it rhymes with (and chimes with) “crappy”. Chacun a son goût.

@David and "happy",  "clappy",  and many others.  I recall having to have an air-gapped system explained to me in '96

In IT, this would be a sparse list or array, and your favorite programming language likely already has an implementation: here's sparse-list for Python. The name comes from the mathematical concept of a sparse matrix, which is a mostly empty two-dimensional array.
However, sparse-anything (sparse file, sparse network, etc) in IT implies that there's magic happening behind the scenes to compress it. For example, if you have a sparse list of a single one followed by a million zeroes, it would be stored in some type of hashmap/dict, squeezing it into a couple of bytes:
{ 0: 1, default: 0 }
This is much more space-efficient and possibly faster to process than a regular list, which would require a million bytes to store:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
So if you're naming an instance of a regular list as sparse_list, code readers are likely to assume it's a special sparse list type. If you're actually implementing a sparse list data structure, the name is of course fine.

Is this not a duplicate of another answer given ten hours previously?

@AndrewLeach StuartF's answer is fine from a general English POV, but OP is asking about this in an IT context and I'm trying to explain the additional nuances there.

That's exactly what I aim to do, thank you.


Porous: "With many gaps"
Perforated: "Pierced with holes"


The word you want is lacunary, which means "relating to lacunae", which is just English, as usual, running off to Latin for a fancy word, in this case one meaning "gaps".
The only problem with "lacunary" is that the only people who will recognize it are mathematicians who have come across the subject of lacunary series.

and manuscript people - lacuna are lost bits of manuscript pages - dog ears, tears, and holes. Lacunar (no y) is the normal adjective outside math.

It might help if we knew what the values are for or why there would be missing ones.
As for the words you could use;
Unfulfilled data,
Void points, since a void lacks anything,
Unnecessary data, but again I don't know if the same point would be filled later,
Unused, if this is for a item check and not all checks apply to the current item.
I hope these suggestions at least get your mind in the right direction for what you are going for.

Other possible words in ordinary English include: partial, incomplete and fragmentary, although some of these don’t have the right technical definition in mathematics. For example, a partial series is the finite sum of the first terms of a series, which is not what you are talking about here.
